# d3js: Bubble getting cut down from edge

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bubble-chart

I am trying to plot some data using bubble chart. I have 5 different circles of different radius. The circle with the bggest radius is getting cut down at the edge as shown in the link [bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grE1q.png)

The script that I have is as shown below:

```
var margin = 40,
width = 600,
height = 400;

var data = [{"admit_probability":54,"rank":20, "c":12},
            {"admit_probability":79,"rank":111, "c":9},
            {"admit_probability":70,"rank":68, "c":6},
            {"admit_probability":12,"rank":1, "c":20},
            {"admit_probability":197,"rank":87, "c":10}];

var xscale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.admit_probability; }))
              .nice() 
              .range([0, width]);

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d.rank; }))
              .nice()
              .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xscale);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(yscale);

var svg = d3.select('.chart')
                .append('svg')
                .attr('class', 'chart')
                .attr("width", width + margin + margin)
                .attr("height", height + margin + margin)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);


svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);


var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

svg.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .insert("circle")
   .attr("cx", width / 2)
   .attr("cy", height / 2)
   .attr("opacity", 0.3)
   .attr("r", function (d) { return (xscale(+d.admit_probability))/10; })
   .style("fill", function (d) { return color(+d.c); })
   .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
        fade(+d.c, .1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
        fadeOut();
    })
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) { return xscale(+d.admit_probability) - yscale(+d.rank); })
    .duration(500)
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return xscale(+d.admit_probability); })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return yscale(+d.rank); });


// // Add the text label for the x axis
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + " ," + (height + margin) + ")")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Average Acceptance");

// // Add the text label for the Y axis
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 0 - margin)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Rank");

function fade(c, opacity) {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function (d) {
          return d.c != c;
      })
    .transition()
     .style("opacity", 0.1);
}

function fadeOut() {
    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .transition()
    .style("opacity", 0.3);
}
```

So, I have two doubts. 
1) How do fit all bubbles of different sizes within the axes range?
2) Is there any general tip to keep in mind while doing so? I am new at this and in general face this issue a lot. 
3) The text of x-axis is also not correctly visible. The 'g' of average acceptance has cut down from below.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The main question is, why do you need radius to be scaled to `d.admit_probability`? That information is already encoded in the x-position of the circle, so you are basically presenting redundant information. If you want the x-axis to accommodate the right most circle + it's diameter (half of radius), then you need to add the largest diameter to the domain of the `xscale`.

Comment: Basically, I was trying to make a bubble bigger if its admit_probability is high. But, yes I get your point. I haven't added sufficient domain to accomodate the whole right most circle. I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: When I looked at your code again I realized that changing the domain doesn't work, since you are doing the "divide by 10" transformation after `xscale()`. In that case, you should simply reduce the range of `xscale`, to something like `.range([0, width * 0.9])` so that you free up enough space on the right side.

Comment: Yeah. got it. Worked. Thanks again :)